# SQLAlchemy Asyncio ORM Unable to Query Database When Retrieving Tables and Columns from MetaData

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm, python-3.7

Using SQLAlchemy async ORM 1.4, Postgres backend, Python 3.7

I am using an `augmented Declarative Base` with the SA ORM. The tables are not held in `models.py` but are committed directly to the database by parsing a JSON script that contains all the table schemas. Because of this, I can't import the models at the top of the script like `from models import ThisTable`.

So to work with CRUD operations on the tables, I first retrieve them by reflecting the metadata.

In the 'usual' way, when importing all the tables at the top of the script, a query like this works:

```
result = await s.execute(select(func.sum(TableName.column)))
curr = result.all()
```

When I try to reflect the table and column objects from the MetaData in order to query them, this doesn't work. There are lots of `AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'func'` or `TypeError: 'Table' object is not callable`errors.

```
def retrieve_table_obj(table):
    meta = MetaData()
    meta.reflect(bind=sync_engine)
    return meta.tables[table]

def retrieve_table_cols(self, table):
    table = retrieve_table_obj('users')
    return table.columns.keys()

async def reading(collection, modifications):

    table = db.retrieve_table_obj(collection)
    columns = db.retrieve_table_cols(collection)
    for c in columns:
        for f in mods['fields']:
            if c in f:
                q = select(func.sum(table.c))

result = await s.execute(q)
curr = result.all()

asyncio.run(reading("users", {'fields': ["usage", "allowance"]}))
```

How can I query tables and columns in the database when they first have to be explicitly retrieved?

Comment: You could use the automap extension to build models via reflection.

Comment: Thanks for the automap suggestion! It works great with a sync engine, but I am working with an async engine and am having trouble getting automap to work with it, even when obtaining an engine connection and calling the function with conn.run_sync. Have you had success using automap with async engine instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The automap extension can be used to automatically reflect database tables to SQLAlchemy models.  However automap uses `inspect` on the engine, and this isn't supported on async engines; we can work around this by doing the automapping using a synchronous engine.  Once the models have been mapped they can be used by the async engine.

For example:

```py
import asyncio

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base


sync_engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql:///test', echo=True, future=True)

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(sync_engine, reflect=True)


async def async_main(collection, modifications):
    engine = create_async_engine(
        "postgresql+asyncpg:///test",
        echo=True,
        future=True,
        connect_args={'ssl': False},
    )

    async_session = orm.sessionmaker(
        engine, class_=AsyncSession, future=True
    )

    async with async_session() as session:
        model = Base.classes[collection]
        matches = set(model.__mapper__.columns.keys()) & set(modifications['fields'])
        for m in matches:
            q = sa.select(sa.func.sum(getattr(model, m)))


            result = await session.execute(q)
            curr = result.all()
            for row in curr:
                print(row)
            print()

    # for AsyncEngine created in function scope, close and
    # clean-up pooled connections
    await engine.dispose()


asyncio.run(reading("users", {'fields': ["usage", "allowance"]}))
```

If you don't need models, caching the `MetaData` object rather than recreating it on every call to `retrieve_table_obj` would make the existing code more efficient, and replacing `select(func.sum(table.c))` with `select(sa.func.sum(getattr(table.c, c)))`

Comment: Thanks for this! I am going to try to integrate this into my code and see how it goes. Just to clarify about your caching suggestion: Do you mean just making the call once and storing it in a list and then throughout the rest of the code pulling from the list rather than the database? Is a `list` the best data type in which to store the `MetaData` object? I much prefer the clarity and succinctness of `select(func.sum(table.c))` rather than `select(sa.func.sum(getattr(table.c, c)))`, so I would l like to preserve `select(func.sum(table.c))`  type of syntax wherever possible.

Comment: I would just keep the metadata object itself, otherwise a dict; searching a long list can be expensive.  I don't see how `table.c` can work, but if you can make it work that's fine.  `table.c[column_name]` would be another option.

Comment: Right, that makes sense! Thanks again

Comment: Regarding building up a query bit by bit with multiple conditions, if I have an update function: 
```async def updater(table_name, where_condition, data):

Table = models_cache.classes[table_name]

async with session_maker() as session:
    query = update(Table).filter_by(**where_condition)
    query = query.values(**data)

    await session.execute(query)
    await session.commit()

asyncio.run(updater('appuser', {'name': 'Cheshire'}, {'org': 'Wonderland'}))
```
I am not sure how to integrate your great example above with this.

Comment: For example, if we want a SQL query that looks something like:

`UPDATE appuserSET org = 'Wonderland'WHERE (name = 'Alice' OR name = 'Cheshire') AND (id > 0);`

And we call the function with parameters like:

```asyncio.run(updater('appuser', {'name': 'Cheshire'}, 
                {'or': [{'name': 'Alice'}]}, 
                {'and': [{'id': '> 0'}]}, 
                {'org': 'Wonderland'}))```
How can we gradually build up a query line by line?