# SQLAlchemy running on Kubernetes Pod, broken behaviour compared to localhost: Async issue / Missing Greenlet

Tags: python, kubernetes, sqlalchemy

When running an API (using FastAPI) I'm building on my Localhost it works as intended, when deploying it to a kubernetes pod it does not. It is unclear to me as to why, though the error appears to suggest an async issue. This seems unusual to me, as I would also expect this to then also be an issue on the localhost.

Having looked into the code and the traceback, the issue appears to be triggered by the following line of my code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from .db_connection import engine

metadata_obj = MetaData()
metadata_obj.reflect(bind=engine)   # <---- this is the problematic line.

my_table = metadata_obj["my_table"]
```

I am aware Table reflection as above is not ideal, and am in the planning to change this. However, due to dependencies this is not possible at this time.

the engine is build as follows:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

database_url = mysql+mysqlconnector://root:@localhost:3306/my_db  # local
database_url = mysql+aiomysql://project_name:pass@db_link:3306/db_name  # pod

engine = create_engine(database_url)
```

As far as I can see the environment should be equivalent, same python version, same libraries.

Thus my question: Why does this cause an issue in the deployment pod, but not on my localhost? And what is the best approach to fixing this?

Full traceback, some names obfuscated.

````
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 189, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 148, in _get_module_details
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 112, in _get_module_details
  File "/app/folder_name/server/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .app import app
  File "/app/folder_name/server/app.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .routes.device import router as device_router
  File "/app/folder_name/server/routes/device.py", line 9, in <module>
    from folder_name.database.db_reader import read_credentials
  File "/app/folder_name/database/db_reader.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .db_tables import my_table
  File "/app/folder_name/database/db_tables.py", line 12, in <module>
    metadata_obj.reflect(bind=engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 5725, in reflect
    with inspection.inspect(bind)._inspection_context() as insp:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/inspection.py", line 145, in inspect
    ret = reg(subject)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 303, in _engine_insp
    return Inspector._construct(Inspector._init_engine, bind)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 236, in _construct
    init(self, bind)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 247, in _init_engine
    engine.connect().close()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3269, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3293, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 645, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/aiomysql.py", line 264, in connect
    await_only(creator_fn(*arg, **kw)),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 121, in await_only
    raise exc.MissingGreenlet(
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)```
````

Comment: Just figured out the db_url uses a different dialect than I have been using locally, I did not set up the db_url in the pod originally. I strongly suspect this causes the issue, thus I have added it to the question. The question on how to fix the problem still stands.

Comment: Note how the call to `metadata.create` is performed in [this example](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#synopsis-core) - I expect `metadata.reflect` must be called in the same way.

Comment: Do you need to deal with asynchronous things in your code? If not why are you using "aiomysql" for your DB dialect?

Comment: Most of my code isn't async; this might change. Async code in the project, written by someone else, led to setting up the pod with an async engine.

My problem is caused by an async dialect with a sync engine builder - within the pod. Changing the builder fixes this, but breaks `metadata.reflect` as [reflection (which uses inspection) requires a sync-engine.](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/errors.html#error-xd3s) Looks like there is a workaround in the documentation, similar to @snakecharmerb's suggestion.

[Question with a similar issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70172248/)